# How can I change my authors mapping file in subgit?

Tags: subgit

I have used subgit to create a standalone mirror from svn repository as git repository using`subgit configure --layout auto SVN_REPO`. THe main functionality is working great, but I am trying to map svn authors into git user names and viceversa,

By using `subgit configure --layout auto SVN_REPO` the mapping file `authors.txt` was created automatically as described in its [documentation](https://subgit.com/documentation/authors-mapping.html#automatic_mapping)

```
user1 = user1 <user2@localhost>
user2 = user2 <user2@localhost>
...
```

I have tried to modify the file `authors.txt` in such a way that it would look like

```
user1 = peter <peter@localhost>
user2 = rob   <rob2@localhost>
...
```

and after that I have issue the command `subgit fetch` in subgit installation folder. However, I still see the old mapping ( using `user1`,`user2`...) instead the names themselves in my cloned git repo.

What should I do to make subgit use my authors mapping? Should I issue the command `subgit configure` again to import the whole svn repository with the new `authors.txt` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing names in the authors file is not enough: the matter is that SubGit sets authors during the actual translation from SVN to Git (or back). So changes made the authors file don't change authors in already translated commits or revisions, those changes will only affect later commits that are created after the authors mapping is changed. If you want that authors mapping to be applied to all commits, then you would need to re-translate the whole repository from scratch, it can be done with 'subgit install --rebuild ' command.

If you mean that new commits are being created with authors from the old mapping, then the most probably that caused by an incorrect path to the authors file, try to check core.authorsFile setting.